# Proof of the "time averaging theorem"

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I have been looking around for a proof or reference for a theorem from my old notes:

The "Time Averaging Theorem" states that if
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix} A(\mathbf{r},t)\\
B(\mathbf{r},t) 
\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} a(\mathbf{r})\\
b(\mathbf{r}) 
\end{bmatrix} e^{-i \omega t}
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{T} \int_0^T \text{Re}(A) \text{Re}(B) dt = \frac{1}{2} \text{Re}(a b^*) 
\end{align}

I remember this "theorem" (if it qualifies as such) being handy for proving certain things with time-harmonic equations in electromagnetism. But I think maybe I have the name wrong in my notes, or that maybe the proof is trivial and nobody bothers to name this thing, because I'm unable to find a reference to it with a bit of googling. How can this be proved? Does it have another name?